# Receive reply in Email Service

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I am new to Email Service concepts in salesforce. Please help me out.

I am working in Email to Case. When someone send email from outside to salesforce then new case record should be created which set some of its fields and reply back to user with case id . I am able to achieve it. Code is here:

```
global class CreateCase implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope env){
Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
Case caseObj= new Case();

    caseObj.Subject=email.subject;
    caseObj.Description=email.plaintextbody;
    caseObj.Status='Open';  

    QueueSObject QueueID = [Select Queue.Id, Queue.Name, Queue.Type from QueueSObject WHERE 
                            Queue.Name ='Case Open Queue' Limit 1];
    caseObj.OwnerId=QueueID.Queue.Id;

    insert caseObj;

   result.message='Thanks for sending mail. Case is successfully created and the case id is:'+caseObj.Id;

   return result;
  }
}
```

Now what i want is user again reply back to same email then emailservice should handle this reply and set  case comments related list of case record  with body of reply.

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 1):

When Case is created you send auto response with case Id. Instead of sending case Id in auto response send case number. because it's hard to identify Id from string subject by regex. and use below code

```
global class CreateCase implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope env){
Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
    String caseNumber;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile('\\d{8}+');
    Matcher m = p.matcher(email.Subject);
    while(m.find()){
        caseNumber = m.group();
    }
    if(caseNumber == null) {
        Case caseObj= new Case();
        caseObj.Subject=email.subject;
        caseObj.Description=email.plaintextbody;
        caseObj.Status='Open';  

        QueueSObject QueueID = [Select Queue.Id, Queue.Name, Queue.Type from QueueSObject WHERE 
                                Queue.Name ='Case Open Queue' Limit 1];
        caseObj.OwnerId=QueueID.Queue.Id;

        insert caseObj;

        result.message='Thanks for sending mail. Case is successfully created and the case id is:'+caseObj.Id;
    } else { //If subject contains case number create case comment instead of a new case.
        Case caseObj = [ SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE CaseNumber = :caseNumber];
        CaseComment caseCommentObj = new CaseComment(ParentId = caseObj.Id, CommentBody= email.Subject +'\n'+ email.plaintextbody);
        insert caseCommentObj;
        //result.message='Thanks for sending mail. email is attached to case comment'+caseObj.Id;
    }

   return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: When mail came from salesforce it appears to come from my gmail account which i have linked with that org and in via some salesforce domain is written. But when i am replying back to the mail to update case comment object. It is replying on my gmail and nort able to receive case comment body.

Comment: You can start auto forwarding from your gmail(Email which you are using for auto response) to Email service email in salesforce.

Comment: Not getting can you please elaborate why code is not receiving case comment record...what is the need of gmail forwarding

Comment: Email will come into salesforce only when it is sent to Email service created in salesforce. You can find that email from setup --> Email Services--> click on email service which you are using. At the bottom there will be a long email address. copy that email and start auto forwarding from your gmail to that email address.

Comment: In my requirement if user replied to the mail then only case comment record is created then why to use auto forwarding from gmail. Also it is asking for some verification code

Comment: You need to use auto forwarding to salesforce because salesforce will not be able to detect email from your gmail inbox. If you will debug email body in Email service class then you will get verification code. If you have implemented above class then you can get verification code in case body as case will be created for that email, check  latest case.

Comment: i ran the code but not able to get verification code in debug log. How to get it

Comment: In Email service there should be a context user, set debug logs for that user. In Email service class add debug statement for email body. Then click on verify in auto-forward setting in gmail. You should get verification code in debug log.

Comment: can you please tell debug statement there is no system.debug(email.body) exists

Comment: email.plaintextbody

Comment: Thanks Amit.. I have verified email. Now can you tell me how to add record of case comment when i reply back to mail

Comment: 1) In auto response rule email subject add casenumber merge field. 2)Send email from an email (don't use gmail where you have auto forwarding configured) to where auto forwarding is configured. 3)You will get auto response subject will be contain case number. 4) reply on that email case comment should be created.

Comment: why we are creating a auto response rule? Actually user has to reply to mail and wahtever user reply in mail that should appear as body of case comments

Comment: No two auto response rules only one. We are adding case number in subject because based on that number existing case can be identified. Its hard to find case if from subject by regex.

Comment: I will be very thankful to you if you will explain steps how to achieve my requirement. Till now i am able to send mail to salesforce and getting case id in reply. As suggested by  you i have added and verified salesforce email address from my gmail account. I want to reply on same mail & body should populate case comment's body. Thanks..